# 2 javascript codes in conflict

Tags: javascript, browser

I have 2 codes.

First:

```
if (typeof website == 'undefined') {
    window.location = "../#!404";
}
```

Second:

```
function credits(){

if (!$("input[name='choices']:checked").val()) {
       var choice = "5";
    }
    else {
      var choice = $("input[name='choices']:checked").val();
    }
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'./core/credits.php',
        data:"smscode="+$('#smscode').val()+"&choices="+choice,
        success:function(response){
            if(response=='1'){$('#sms_label').css({'display':'block','border':'1px solid #bfde84','background':'#edfbd8 url(../images/success.gif) 12px 12px no-repeat','color':'#508600',}).html('Успешно заредихте 1 кредит')}
            else if(response=='2'){$('#sms_label').css({'display':'block','border':'1px solid #e9c59b','background':'#ffecce url(../images/error.gif) 12px 12px no-repeat','color':'#e3302c',}).html('Моля изберете колко кредита искате да заредите')}
            else if(response=='3'){$('#sms_label').css({'display':'block','border':'1px solid #e9c59b','background':'#ffecce url(../images/error.gif) 12px 12px no-repeat','color':'#e3302c',}).html('Моля въведете SMS код')} 
            else if(response=='4'){$('#sms_label').css({'display':'block','border':'1px solid #e9c59b','background':'#ffecce url(../images/error.gif) 12px 12px no-repeat','color':'#e3302c',}).html('Въведеният SMS код е грешен или изтекъл')} 
if(response=='5'){$('#sms_label').css({'display':'block','border':'1px solid #bfde84','background':'#edfbd8 url(../images/success.gif) 12px 12px no-repeat','color':'#508600',}).html('Успешно заредихте 2 кредита')}
if(response=='6'){$('#sms_label').css({'display':'block','border':'1px solid #bfde84','background':'#edfbd8 url(../images/success.gif) 12px 12px no-repeat','color':'#508600',}).html('Успешно заредихте 4 кредита')}
if(response=='7'){$('#sms_label').css({'display':'block','border':'1px solid #bfde84','background':'#edfbd8 url(../images/success.gif) 12px 12px no-repeat','color':'#508600',}).html('Успешно заредихте 6 кредита')}
        }
    });
}
```

The website variable is defined in index.php

```
var website = true;
```

Both codes work okay when are separated but when i combine them into 1 file.

Second code works, first one doesn't.

Comment: y have '..' in your path? It should be relative or absolute like:
http://example.com/test or /test

Comment: @ChiragJain: `../` **is** a relative link.

Comment: might consider moving all your inline css to style sheet and changing classes instead. Doesn't solve problem but will make code a lot more readable

Comment: what errors are thrown in console?

Comment: You're missing the ending `{` for your credits() function. That could be a copy and paste error however.

Comment: If the `var website = true;` comes *after* the `<script>` tag that imports the JavaScript code, the test will fail.

Comment: @charlietfl "Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" jquery.js:16

Comment: How do you use the code from those 2 (combined) files? BTW, each `.css()` has one unnecessary comma just before closing `})`. See `,})`. And with `switch` code could be more readable. You use `if`, `else if` and again `if`.